# How do I know if my AJAX request is vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, security, xss

A security firm surprise audited a web app I work on, and told me that there are XSS vulnerabilities. I don't really know where to begin.

This is the AJAX:

```
new Form.Observer('filter', 0.5, function(element, value) 
{
    startLoad('proposals');; 
    new Ajax.Updater('proposals', 'http://acme.example.dev/stuff/filter', 
        {
            asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request)
                {
                }, parameters:value + '&authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('base64StringHere')
        })
});
```

Comment: What webserver are you using? It's possible that there is an XSS filter you can stick in on the server side.

Comment: Also, why did you set evalScripts to true? Are there some scripts you're intending to execute? If they can contain user input, it needs to be sanitized.

Comment: And another question--what is supposed to go in 'proposals'--is it plain text, or does the server generate HTML?

Comment: @Annie: Webrick: It's a RoR app.  So these things are set by default.  That stopLoad is a function for animating progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure how to track down the vulnerability, since it's not clear what user input your page is displaying. Since you're using RoR, the best place to start is probably the [XSS section of the RoR security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss).

You could also try running a scanner like [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/). It will try to automatically detect XSS and other security vulnerabilities, and if it finds them it will give you some details and documentation to help fix the problem.

Comment: I can't get the parameters right. =\ It says it is really easy to use... haha.     Following http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/wiki/SkipfishDoc   And substituting their domain with mine.